# Change sets including custom objects and custom fields

Tags: ide, migration-tool, change-set, field-level-security

I have always been curious how other developers deploy custom objects and fields.  If I have a small amount of development work in sandbox, I can just recreate the new custom objects and fields in production first, and then deploy the Apex and VF using the IDE.  When I have bigger projects, it seems easier to use change sets to I can add the custom objects and custom fields within the change set. This avoids having to recreate every object and every field in production.

However, when I do this, each custom field on every custom object has nothing set in the field level security.  So I now have to go through and update the field level security on every field for every object.  This can be highly time consuming and monotonous if you have a good number of objects and fields.

How are other people deploying Objects and Fields?  Should I be using the migration tool?  I have never really explored it, is it tough to set up and use? Am I missing something or doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour happens because whenever you migrate fields and objects make sure you include the profiles also in the outbound  changeset .Since profile metadata along with fields and objects metadata define field level security

Official documentation link:

http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/changesets_best_practices.htm

Comment: Glad that it helped